# What options do i have for generating .net bytecode?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, code-generation, cil

I would prefer an API approach rather than going via CIL. Are there any high level frameworks I could use, or should I use Reflection.Emit?

UPDATE

In exploring further I noticed that there are (potentially) conflicting explanations about what is used at the back end of the Mono mcs.exe C# compiler. [Some](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/docs/compiler.txt) say that "*The Mono C# compiler generates ECMA CIL images through the use of the System.Reflection.Emit API*" while [elsewhere](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#New_C.23_Compiler_Backend) it is stated that as of September 2011 mcs was using the IKVM.NET [implementation](http://www.ikvm.net/) for bytecode generation.

Comment: C# is a fairly "high level framework" for generating CIL :)

Comment: Too vague.  Maybe http://cciast.codeplex.com/

Comment: Apologies for the lack of detail - I wrote it quickly on my phone on a bumpy bus trip. I meant the Compiler tag to indicate that I need to use this framework as a code generation back-end to a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on what you're trying to achieve. Without knowing your particular scenario, it's hard to suggest the right tool for the job.

If you need to generate dynamic methods at runtime, `Reflection.Emit` is perfect for that. If you're looking to modify your assembly, look no further than [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). Keep in mind that all these tools require understanding of the .NET metadata and MSIL.

However, if you're trying to do something that requires, for instance, inspection or modification of types or methods, you might want to look at an AOP solution like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com). It will let you express those needs in a much higher level than MSIL.

Again, it all very much depends on your usecase.

*Disclaimer: I work at SharpCrafters, creators of PostSharp*

Comment: I'm looking at creating the back end code generation for a compiler. I can of course generate textual IL, but would rather be able to stream directly to bytecode rather than have to have an extra pass to convert IL.

Comment: So, an IL rewriter like postsharp or a C# based framework that imposes a particular form of semantics is probably not appropriate for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Bytecode is not high-level. If you want to generate bytecode at a high level, write in a proper language, and use a compiler... :)

If you want to generate bytecode, it is per definition low-level.

What is it that you want to achieve? Maybe it is possible using other techniques than IL emitting? There are many ways of manipulating classes runtime in .net without using IL.

Comment: There are helper APIs with a marginally higher level of abstraction to assist with emitting IL/byte-code. I remember one being mentioned on the code-project years ago, but I can't recall the name. It may have been abandoned years ago.

Comment: Also you may want to be the one writing the compiler!